# how to handle realtime mqtt data in backend to response in html page

Tags: backend, mqtt, real-time-data

I want to make an app that sends realtime mqtt data. The backend will catch this mqtt stream. I need this data to manipulate a realtime graph on a webpage. How can I do this? What are the best practices to handle this realtime data? Should I process every incoming mqqt request? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have multiple options, that are depending on your use case.

1. Use Eclipse Paho JavaScript to directly connect to the MQTT broker from within the web browser. I have done a similar use case as you descirbe at EclipseCon Europe. A Java client publishes random data and the web page shows a temperature gauge and other charts. Code and slides are available [here](https://github.com/dc-square/mqtt-with-paho-eclipsecon2013).
2. Let your MQTT broker save all publishes to a database (see [best practises](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/)). For getting the data to the browser I would recommend a REST API. With this option you can easily show historic data.

Hope that answers your question.

Cheers,
Chris